# PostgreSQL ERROR column does not exist refers to a column value

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a table `projects` in postgreSQL that looks like below

```
id.    project_name.   col3.  col4
1111.   test.          ...    ...
```

I want to insert a new row for a new `id` only if the `id` does not already exist. So I wrote below query

```
INSERT INTO projects(id, project_name)
VALUES("1234", "Test_Project")
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO NOTHING
```

But it throws me an error

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  column "1234" does not exist
LINE 2: VALUES("1234", "Test_Project_...
```

Please suggest.

** EDIT**

The `id` column in the table is a uuid and not unique. There can be multiple rows with the same id. Based on GMBs suggestion, I tried below

```
INSERT INTO projects(id, project_name)
    VALUES('1234', 'Test_Project')
    ON CONFLICT (create unique index on projects(id))
    DO NOTHING
```

I get below error with it

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "create"
LINE 3: ON CONFLICT (create unique index on projects(id...
```

I am new to this so I am sure missing something obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use single quotes for literal strings. Double quotes stand for identifiers (such as column names or table names) - hence the error that you are getting:

```
INSERT INTO projects(id, project_name)
VALUES('1234', 'Test_Project')
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO NOTHING
```

That said, I would suspect that `id` is of `integer` datatype. If so, don't quote it at all:

```
INSERT INTO projects(id, project_name)
VALUES(1234, 'Test_Project')
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO NOTHING
```

Comment: `id` is uuid. I tried both the approach, with single quote, I get below error `Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification`. This `id` values are not necessarily unique in the table. There can be multiple rows on the same id. Hence I am getting this error I think.

Comment: @nad: `on conflict` requires a unique index (or a primary key) on the related column. `create unique index on projects(id)`.